# Picker creation in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, picker

I am trying to build a custom picker, but I have encountered a problem. I have created cell, EntityType and picker itself. This code suppose to update selectedEntityType and then change the main view. It's not updating the EntityType, therefore not changing view. I don't provide MainView because it's not the problem, it's not updating Entity. Can someone explain what's wrong?

```
import Foundation

enum EntityType: String, Identifiable, CaseIterable {
    case all
    case album
    case song
    
    var id: String {
        self.rawValue
    }

    func name() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .all:
            return "Stories for falling asleep"
        case .album:
            return "Sounds of nature"
        case .song:
            return "Meditations for sleep"
        
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReusableNavigationBarCell: View {
    
    var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
       
        Button {
            
        } label: {
            
            ZStack {
                
                Text(text)
                    .padding()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .background(Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color("active"))
                        .cornerRadius(8)
                        .frame(height: 36))
                
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ReusableNavigationBarCell_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReusableNavigationBarCell(text: "Stories for falling asleep")
        
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct ReusableNavigationBar: View {
    
    @State var selectedEntityType = EntityType.all
    
    let rows = Array(repeating: GridItem(.fixed(30), spacing: 0, alignment: .leading), count: 1)
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            LazyHGrid(rows: rows, spacing: 8) {
                
                ForEach(EntityType.allCases, id: \.self) { type in
                    ReusableNavigationBarCell(text: type.name())
                        .tag(type)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedEntityType = type
                        }
                }
                
            }
        }
        .frame(height: 38)
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
        .padding(.horizontal, 10.0)
    }
}

struct ReusableNavigationBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReusableNavigationBar()
            .background(.yellow)
    }
}
```

Comment: `selectedEntityType` in your `ReusableNavigationBar` should be `@Binding` instead of `@State` so you can listen its change in MainView

Comment: Yes, I've figured it out and fixed it. Thanks!)